# Need help clearing markers from a map - Google Maps API V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a map that is doing everything that I need it to do, but I am having trouble w/ setting up a proper global array to store my markers and then clearing it when a new selection is made from the **loadFromCitySelect()** function (via drop down). I have tried clearing the **Global_gmarkers** array between **load()** function calls (ie. every time you choose a new location with the citySelect function noted above). I can't seem to figure out why it's not actually working. If someone could point out what needs to be repaired to have the markers clear between each **loadFromCitySelect()** call, I'd greatly appreciate it.

```
function loadFromCitySelect(){
    //get selected city
    var city = getSelectedValue("city_select");
    load(LANGUAGE,city,0,-1);
}

function loadFromOfficeSelect(){
    //get selected city
    var city = getSelectedValue("city_select");
    var office = getSelectedValue("office_select");
    load(LANGUAGE,city,office,-1);
    //LANGUAGE was initially set when the page was first loaded
}

var Global_side_bar_html;
var Global_gmarkers;
var Global_htmls;
var Global_i;
var Global_points;
var Global_lasti;
var courtIcon = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal2/icon10.png";
var iconONT = courtIcon;
    iconONT.image = courtIcon;
    iconONT.iconSize = new google.maps.Size(40, 40);
    iconONT.iconAnchor = new google.maps.Point(15, 15);
    iconONT.infoWindowAnchor = new google.maps.Point(17, 2);

// activate the InfoWindow and store it
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    size: new google.maps.Size(250,200) //not actually sure that this does anything?
});

/*    FUNCTIONS    */
/*******************/
function createInfoMarker(point, info, icon, name, num) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: point,
        icon: courtIcon,
        map: map
    });
    // Global_gmarkers.push(marker);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(Global_htmls[num]);
        infoWindow.open(map,marker);
        // map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        document.getElementById("printInfoBubble").innerHTML = info;
    });

    Global_gmarkers[Global_i] = marker;
    Global_htmls[Global_i] = info;
    Global_points[Global_i] = point;
    Global_side_bar_html += '<a id="'+Global_i+'" onmouseover="map_listings_highlight('+Global_i+');" onmouseout="map_listings_unhighlight('+Global_i+');" href="javascript:topListClick(' + Global_i + ')" class="listtag">' + name + '</a><br>';
    Global_i++;

    return marker;
} // end createInfoMarker

function topListClick(i){
    google.maps.event.trigger(Global_gmarkers[i], "click");
}

function init(){
    var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 12,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.717272, -79.393044),
            scrollwheel: false,
            scaleControl: true,
            overviewMapControl: true,
            overviewMapControlOptions:{opened:true},
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    window.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

    //gather url string arguments
    LANGUAGE = getQueryVariable("lang"); //?lang=
    CITY = getQueryVariable("city"); //?city=
    COURT = getQueryVariable("court");
    PCODE = getQueryVariable("pcode");
    //if no url string arguments were passed, use the following as default
    if (CITY==""){
        CITY = 122; //Toronto as default
    }
    if (LANGUAGE==""){
        LANGUAGE = "en"; //EN by default
    }
    if (COURT==""){
        COURT = -1; //no court was passed
    }
    if (PCODE!=""){
        document.getElementById("postal_code").value = PCODE;
    }
    //load language variables
    initText(LANGUAGE);
    load(LANGUAGE,CITY,0,COURT);
}

function load(lang,city_id,office_id,court_id){
    Global_side_bar_html = "";
    Global_gmarkers = [];
    Global_htmls = [];
    Global_i = 0;
    Global_points = [];
    Global_lasti = -1;

    var xhr;
    try { xhr = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP'); }
    catch (e) 
    {
    try { xhr = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP'); }
        catch (e2) 
        { try { xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); }
        catch (e3) { xhr = false; }
        }
    }

    xhr.onreadystatechange  = function()
    { 
    if(xhr.readyState == 4)
        {
            if(xhr.status  == 200) {
                var doc = xhr.responseXML;   // Assign the XML file to a var
                var courts = doc.getElementsByTagName('court');
                var index = -1;
                var LAT;
                var LNG;

                //BEGIN LOAD SEQUENCE LOGIC

                //
                // 1) get specific court information if the city_id variable is not "-1"
                //

                if (court_id!=-1){ //if the court_id variable was specified in the URL, get the city to which this single court belongs
                    for (var i = 0; i <= courts.length-1; i++) {    
                        if(courts[i].getAttribute("court_id")==court_id){//for this single court...
                            city_id = courts[i].getAttribute("city_id"); //find its city
                            LAT = courts[i].getAttribute("lat"); //record this court's location
                            LNG = courts[i].getAttribute("lng");                            
                            break; //break for loop as court has been found
                         } //end if
                     }//end for
                }//end if

                //
                // 2) load the city select and use city_id as the selected city
                //

                if (CITYSELECT==0){ 
                    var opts = [];
                    var vals = [];
                    var tempval;
                    var tempopt;
                    for (var i=0;i<=courts.length-1;i++){
                        tempval = courts[i].getAttribute("city_id");
                        tempopt = courts[i].getAttribute("city");
                        if (!valueExists(vals,tempval)){
                            vals[vals.length] = tempval;
                            opts[opts.length] = tempopt;
                        }
                    }
                    sortOptions(opts,vals);
                    writeSelect("city_select",opts,vals,city_id);
                    CITYSELECT = 1; //flag this so the select is not written again
                }

                //
                // 3) get all offices for this city_id if office_id is "0"
                //

                if (office_id==0){
                    //re-init global array
                    //resetGlobalArray();
                    var temparray = [];
                    temparray[0] = 0;
                    for (var i=0;i<=courts.length-1;i++){
                        if(courts[i].getAttribute("city_id")==city_id){// for this court...
                            recordOffices(temparray,courts[i].getAttribute("civil_scj"),courts[i].getAttribute("crim_y_ocj"),courts[i].getAttribute("crim_scj"),courts[i].getAttribute("crim_ocj"),courts[i].getAttribute("div_scj"),courts[i].getAttribute("enf_scj"),courts[i].getAttribute("fam_scj"),courts[i].getAttribute("fam_ocj"),courts[i].getAttribute("scc_scj"),courts[i].getAttribute("coa"));
                        }//end if 
                    }//end for

                    var tempvals = getUniqueValues(temparray);
                    sortArray(tempvals);
                    var tempopts = getOfficeOptions(LANGUAGE,tempvals);

                    clearSelectOptions("office_select");
                    writeSelect("office_select",tempopts,tempvals,tempvals[0]);

                } //end if office_id==0

                //
                // 4) get all courts for this city_id and office_id
                //

                for (var i = 0; i <= courts.length-1; i++) {
                    if(courts[i].getAttribute("city_id")==city_id){// for this city...
                        if(checkOffice(office_id,courts[i].getAttribute("civil_scj"),courts[i].getAttribute("crim_y_ocj"),courts[i].getAttribute("crim_scj"),courts[i].getAttribute("crim_ocj"),courts[i].getAttribute("div_scj"),courts[i].getAttribute("enf_scj"),courts[i].getAttribute("fam_scj"),courts[i].getAttribute("fam_ocj"),courts[i].getAttribute("scc_scj"),courts[i].getAttribute("coa"))){
                            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(courts[i].getAttribute("lat")), parseFloat(courts[i].getAttribute("lng")));
                            var tempaddress;
                            var tempcourtname;
                            var tempnotes;
                            if (LANGUAGE=="fr"){
                                tempaddress = courts[i].getAttribute("address_fr");
                                tempcourtname = courts[i].getAttribute("name_fr");
                                tempnotes = courts[i].getAttribute("notes_fr");
                            } else {
                                tempaddress = courts[i].getAttribute("address");
                                tempcourtname = courts[i].getAttribute("name");
                                tempnotes = courts[i].getAttribute("notes_en");
                            }

                            var htmlinfo = getInfoString();
                            var marker;

                            if (courts[i].getAttribute("court_id")==court_id){
                                index = Global_i;
                            }
                            //create an info marker for this court
                            //this function also writes these objects for global use
                            createInfoMarker(point,htmlinfo,iconONT,tempaddress,Global_i);
                        }//end if
                    } //end if
                }//end for

                // 
                // 4b) put the markers on the map

                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                var numcourts = Global_gmarkers.length;
                for (var i = 0; i <= numcourts-1; i++){
                    Global_gmarkers[i].setMap(map);
                    bounds.extend(Global_points[i]);
                }

                //
                // 5) write elements to list box above the map canvas
                //    and activate item 0

                document.getElementById("listbox").innerHTML = Global_side_bar_html;
                topListClick(0);

            } else { 
                alert("Error code " + xhr.status);
            } //end if ==200
        } //end if ==4
    } //end function()

   xhr.open("GET", XMLFILE, true);
   xhr.send(null);

}// end load()
```

Comment: loop array and just like you add with setMap, remove with `setMap(null)`  see method description https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference

Comment: @charlietfl I understand the concept, just having trouble making it happen.

Comment: be easier if you didn't post all your code, only sections you have trouble with...too much code stops a lot of people wanting to help...time consuming to read through it

Comment: @charlietfl Point taken. I have edited some of the big chunks that aren't necessary here. Thanks.

Comment: my suggestion would be make a very simple test case...without unnecessary features, or ajax...just a  small array of markers. Add those markers to map , then try to remove them with a button click handler. Then integrte into larger app

Comment: @brentoage did you get a look to my answer? Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

try this changes:

1. In the function **createInfoMarker** uncomment this line **Global_gmarkers.push(marker);**
2. In the function **load** clear the Global_gmarkers of this way:



   `for(var i = 0; i < Global_gmarkers.length; i++){
   Global_gmarkers[i].setAllMap(null);
   }`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a different approach.
When you work with google maps and you have a complex work to do like in your case is better to code your own objects to manage all the hard work.

So I suggest you to have an object *MyMarker* which will have all you need in a marker (the html for the infowindow, the icon, the point...).
Then do have a *MyMarkerCollection* object which will manage the collection of markers.
Get ride of all your *Global** (Global_i, Global_points...) variables if you think they can fit in your *MyMarker* object or *MyMarkerCollection* object (it is easy to do unwanted things when coding with much more global variables than needed).

You will have to accomodate your code a little, but you will see it is a work that worth the trouble.

Get a look to the following code demostrating the new approach:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>    
    <title>Handling markers collection demo</title>

   <style type="text/css">
        html
        {
            height: 100%;
        }
        body
        {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #map-container
        {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            min-width:500px;
            min-height:300px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>    

</head>


<body>
    <button onclick="Load1()">Load Point 1</button>
    <button onclick="Load2()">Load Point 2</button>
    <button onclick="Remove()">Remove</button>
    <div id="map-container"></div>


    <script type="text/javascript"  language="javascript">

        var _map;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 4,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            _map = new google.maps.Map($("#map-container")[0], mapOptions);
        });

        // for the demo sake
        var points1 = [{lat:1.2345, lng: 3.45465}, {lat:-1.45467, lng: 3.54645}];
        var points2 = [{lat:2.2345, lng: -4.45465}, {lat:-2.45467, lng:-4.54645}];

        //very little global variables (only what you really need to be global)
        var MarkersCollection;

        // the custom marker object with all what you need to show along with your marker
        // and some methods in the prototype that help to manage the object
        function MyMarker(point, html) {
            this.point = point; // your point
            this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: this.point}); 
            this.html = html;
        }
        MyMarker.prototype.addMarkerToMap = function (map) {
            this.marker.setMap(map);
        };
        MyMarker.prototype.removeMarkerFomMap = function () {            
            this.marker.setMap(null);
        };

        // the collection of custom markers with the methos that help to manage the collection
        function MyMarkerCollection() {
            this.collection = [];
        }
        MyMarkerCollection.prototype.add = function (marker) {
            this.collection.push(marker);
        };
        MyMarkerCollection.prototype.removeAllMarkers = function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.collection.length; i++) {                
                this.collection[i].removeMarkerFomMap();
            }
        };
        MyMarkerCollection.prototype.count= function () {                             
            return this.collection.length;               
        };


        // your load function
        function Load(points) {

            if (!MarkersCollection) {
                MarkersCollection = new MyMarkerCollection();
            }
            else {
                MarkersCollection.removeAllMarkers();
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
                var point = new google.maps.LatLng(points[i].lat, points[i].lng);
                // create markers
                var marker = new MyMarker(point, "your html");
                marker.addMarkerToMap(_map);
                MarkersCollection.add(marker);

                _map.setCenter(point);
            }
        }

        // for the demo sake
        function Load1() {
            Load(points1);
        }
        function Load2() {
            Load(points2);
        }
        function Remove(){
            if(MarkersCollection)MarkersCollection.removeAllMarkers();
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```